# Storybook keeps crashing with ModuleParseError: Module parse failed Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, msw

I wanted to mock api calls in storybook by using the [msw](https://mswjs.io/) package in my storybook.
but when i try to launch it i get an error.

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (14:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| class Emitter {
>     #events;
|     #maxListeners;
|     #hasWarnedAboutPotentialMemortyLeak;
    at handleParseError (\node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at \node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at \node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at \node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)  
    at Storage.finished (\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at \node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at \node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| exports.MemoryLeakError = void 0;
| class MemoryLeakError extends Error {
>     emitter;
|     type;
|     count;
    at handleParseError (\node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at \node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at \node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at \node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)  
    at Storage.finished (\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at \node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at \node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

heres my storybook config

```
// https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#typescript-module-resolution
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.tsx", "../src/**/*.stories.mdx"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-controls",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs",
    "@storybook/addon-docs",
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.plugins = [
      ...(config.resolve.plugins || []),
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        extensions: config.resolve.extensions,
      }),
    ];
    return config;
  },
};
```

im using storybook v6.5.13, i tried using webpack5 since i noticed a lot of the articles explaning how to use msw had it, so i added

```
core : {
    builder : "webpack5"
  }
```

and the webpack manager + builder, but it just hangs there and never finishes building, so i reverted back.